# How subtract fixed number from SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a SQL Server table like

```
Code      Name         Value
--------------------------------------------
1         A            10
2         B            20
3         C            40
4         d            70
```

how subtract a fixed number like `100` from the SQL Server column, to get a result like this

```
Code      Name         Value      net
--------------------------------------------
1         A            10         90  (100 - 10) 
2         B            20         70  (90 - 20)
3         C            40         30  (70 - 40)
4         d            70        -40  (30 - 70)
```

Please can anyone please help me?

Comment: It would be a lot easier with application code such as .net or ColdFusion if that is available to you.

Comment: This can be easily done with a Common Table Expression... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (100 - (select sum(value)
               from table t2
               where t2.code <= t.code
              )
       ) as net
from table t;
```

In SQL Server 2012, you can do this with a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
       (100 - sum(value) over (order by t.code)
       ) as net
from table t;
```

Comment: You have done something wrong in the second example? From where you get the `t2` alias?